# Getting error while passing two php variable inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting the following error while passing two php variable inside the javascript function.

> Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

My code is given below.

```
<script>
 editQuestionField(<?php echo $GLOBALS['ques'] ?>,<?php echo $GLOBALS['id'] ?>);
</script>
```

its generating the html output in browser console which is given below.

```
editQuestionField(,5742d88fe4017af412000030);
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Your first argument is emtpy echo $GLOBALS['ques']

Answer (score 3):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to pass values to javascript.

```
editQuestionField(<?php echo json_encode($GLOBALS['ques']) ?>,<?php echo json_encode($GLOBALS['id']) ?>);
```

Also `$GLOBALS['ques']` is most likely empty/not defined.

Comment: This is a better suggestion. As double quotes will get escaped.

Answer (score 0):

write values in `''` quotes like this `editQuestionField('val1','val2');`

```
<script>
 editQuestionField('<?php echo $GLOBALS['ques'] ?>','<?php echo $GLOBALS['id'] ?>');
</script>
```